# .flaskenv not starting in development enviornment

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables

I have my .flaskenv file as below

```
FLASK_APP=app.py
FLASK_ENV=development
```

When I run

```
flask run
```

I get the following

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app.py'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
```

As seen, the server, while it says it a development server, it does not run in a development environment. I have the python-dotenv package installed and the .flaskenv file is in the same directory as my app.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`FLASK_DEBUG=1`

for running the server in development mode.

`FLASK_DEBUG=0`

turns the debug mode off